# Set IFrame height using the height attribute, disregarding a CSS rule

Tags: html, css, iframe

Does anyone know why the IFrame won't use the height attribute after specifying a css rule? In the following example, none of the IFrames will have a height of 500px.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        iframe {
            height: 200px;
        }

        iframe.auto {
            height: auto;
        }

        iframe.inherit {
            height: inherit;
        }

        iframe.initial {
            height: initial;
        }

        iframe.revert {
            height: revert;
        }

        iframe.unset {
            height: unset;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe height="500"></iframe>
    <iframe class="auto" height="500"></iframe>
    <iframe class="inherit" height="500"></iframe>
    <iframe class="initial" height="500"></iframe>
    <iframe class="revert" height="500"></iframe>
    <iframe class="unset" height="500"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does `<iframe style="height: 500px"` behave in this case?

Comment: `<iframe style="height: 500px">` will correctly set the height to `500px`. The issue with some 3rd party libraries is that they only update the height attribute of the iframe and not the style definition. Without some sort of hook, observer, or other complex approach, if there are height definitions in CSS that are inherited by the iframe, they will take precedence over the height attribute. There seems to be no way that I can find, to stop the inheritance of the CSS height definitions and fall back to the height attribute.

Comment: For our case, can we just email upstream and ask to update both style and height attrs?

Comment: I reached out to Greg to see if that would be possible. It might be easier for us to scope our current CSS definitions with a class.

Answer (score 0):

In the html style atribute `height` (very old fashion unless writting email code) You can't use "px". It's always "px" by default and it can't be anything else. Just add `height="500"` [More info](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_height.asp)

Comment: Even without the `px` the height still does not fall back to the attribute.